# Intercepting incoming calls android/ios/hybrid

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I need to auto reply undesired phone calls, I have read the related questions(@ConvexMartian), but I din't find a real solution, can be a native (Android/IOS) or a hybrid solution(even better). In fact I need:

1. Intercept incoming calls
2. Auto reply with an audio with number options, press 1 to 3 for example.
3. Get the user response according to keyboard(1-3) selection.

It is this possible to make?

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 but there exist a solution for Android? Do you have an example or some documentation for help?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin to intercept call, but i'm not sure this can do all of the job you want.

Minimum requirements: **iOS 10+** and **Android Marshmallow+**

Plugin: [CordovaCall](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall)

Comment: I found this plugin also but it only works to intercept the Phone call, i will really appreciate if there exist a solution to my problem.